# How can I make a faceted bar chart use stacked bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, facet

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but have tried a million different iterations and can't seem to find the right recipe. I'm working with survey data and faceting it in a facet_grid, which is now working nicely:

```
# ingest some data
df <- structure(list(Q52_bin = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("low", 
"medium", "high"), class = "factor"), Q53_bin = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("low", "medium", "high"), class = "factor"), 
    Q57_bin = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("low", 
    "medium", "high"), class = "factor"), Q4 = c("A little", 
    "Some", "Some", "A great deal", "A lot", "Some")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
# make column names coherent and simplified
names(df) <- c("Q52_bin", "Q53_bin", "Q57_bin", "response")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!response, names_to = "bin_name", values_to = "b") %>% 
  count(response, bin_name, b) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=n,y=response)) +
  geom_col(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_discrete()+
  facet_grid(vars(b), vars(bin_name)) + labs(caption = "How much have you thought about climate change before today?", x = "", y = "")
```

However, what I'd really like is for these bars to be stacked horizontal bars with a single bar inside each facet using colours to indicate the different likert responses. I was thinking I could simply switch to:

```
  ggplot(aes(x=n,fill=response)) +
  geom_bar(position="fill") +
```

but the output is incoherent (zillions of narrow bars).  Any suggestions on how I can switch this as desired?

Comment: Does `ggplot(aes(x = n, y = "", fill = response)) + geom_col(position="stack")` do what you want?

Comment: Yep - that's the ticket. I also changed to position="fill" and that's me sorted. Just need to sort the colours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question but I would assume this is what you are after.

Sample code:

```
 df %>% 
      pivot_longer(!response, names_to = "bin_name", values_to = "b") %>% 
      count(response, bin_name, b) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x=n,y=b, fill=response)) +
      geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
      scale_fill_discrete()+
      facet_grid(vars(b), vars(bin_name)) + 
      labs(caption = "How much have you thought about climate change before today?", x = "", y = "")
```

Plot:

[image]

And if change

```
facet_grid(~b) # b takes values medium and high



  response     bin_name b          n
   <chr>        <chr>    <fct>  <int>
 1 A great deal Q52_bin  medium     1
 2 A great deal Q53_bin  medium     1
 3 A great deal Q57_bin  medium     1
 4 A little     Q52_bin  high       1
 5 A little     Q53_bin  medium     1
 6 A little     Q57_bin  medium     1
 7 A lot        Q52_bin  medium     1
 8 A lot        Q53_bin  medium     1
 9 A lot        Q57_bin  medium     1
10 Some         Q52_bin  medium     3
11 Some         Q53_bin  medium     2
12 Some         Q53_bin  high       1
13 Some         Q57_bin  medium     3
```

If you want to ignore the Q52_bin...-s

[image]

and to make more nicer use a different theme

```
library(ggtheme)

theme_gdocs()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean about `facet_grid(~b)`? I can't seem to make that work in my code.